# The correct way to structure React/Redux for efficient updating

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, redux, react-redux

Our app is built using React and Redux with firebase acting as our back-end.

Our app has a canvas with several types of "entities" on it. These entities are intractable with any user who is currently on the canvas. There can be as many as 300 entities on canvas at a time.

On load, the app goes out and gets all the entities it needs based on a node in firebase. This node is just a list of ids that the canvas needs. Then, each time an id is passed to the app, the app goes out and gets the info for that id and places it in store. Here is an example of a stack entity which can have children entities.

```js
{
  "-KZ6ieI3kUyCjl_3d2jc" : true,
  "-KeKtL8HYhHsKmSLw-Lz" : true,
  "-KeKtLGQyMDLdlz-lmec" : true,
  "-KeKtLO_yBVHwle7QSQc" : true,
  "-KeKtLVvh8iLNfbdOdzV" : true,
  "-KeKtLofe8hLEZ0dfy8E" : true,
  "-KeLA446updVOw_a6EG5" : true,
  "-KeLAKJTTpImhBez5ivt" : true,
  "-KeYp76zg5Z-OJamIDqW" : true,
  "-KeYpmhno-ZAaztlxBtE" : true,
  "-KeYv8PTfMei0bWbllzg" : true,
  "-KeYv8Zo_DeyIlF3d_GA" : true
}

{
  "addNewItemPlaceholder" : false,
  "canvasID" : "-0testDevCanvas",
  "childEntities" : {
    "2" : [ "-KeKtLVvh8iLNfbdOdzV", "-KZ6ieI3kUyCjl_3d2jc", "-KeKtL8HYhHsKmSLw-Lz", "-KeLA446updVOw_a6EG5", "-KeLAKJTTpImhBez5ivt", "-KeKtLO_yBVHwle7QSQc", "-KeYp76zg5Z-OJamIDqW", "-KeYpmhno-ZAaztlxBtE" ]
  },
  "dataX" : 505,
  "dataY" : 570,
  "expanded" : true,
  "height" : "1200px",
  "location" : "-0testDevCanvas",
  "selected" : false,
  "subType" : 0,
  "type" : 1,
  "width" : "1176px"
}
```

Here is an example of the actions.

```js
export function fetchCanvasAndChildren(id, settings = {untrack: false}) {
  //if untrack is set to true then we are just removing all the data and removing the listeners
  if (!settings.untrack) {
    //track the canvas
    trackEntity(id);

    //get all the children and track them
    firebase.database().ref(`entitiesNode/groups/${id}`).on('child_added', child => {
      //track this entity
      trackEntity(child.key);
    });

    firebase.database().ref(`entitiesNode/groups/${id}`).on('child_removed', child => {
      //need to entrack the entity
      //remove the entity from store
      store.dispatch({
        type: 'REMOVE_ENTITY',
        id: child.key
      });
    });
  } else {
    //need to iterate through store and untrack all the entities and remove them from store
    let entities = store.getState().entities;
    for (var entity in entities) {
      untrackEntity(entity);
    }
  }//end untrack if
}

function trackEntity(id) {
  //track the entity and add it to the store
  firebase.database().ref(`entitiesNode/entities/${id}`).on('value', snapshot => {
    //TODO there are sometimes entities in the group that no longer exist. Ignore these but they will need to be cleaned up.
    if (snapshot.val() !== null) {
      let entityObj = snapshot.val();

      // update the store
      store.dispatch({
        type: 'ADD/UPDATE_ENTITY_FROM_FB',
        id,
        payload: entityObj
      });
    }
  });
}

function untrackEntity(id) {
  //remove the listener
  //get the entity types ONCE from firebase and remove listeners based on the entity types even though some may not be used
  firebase.database().ref(`entitiesNode/types`).once('value', typesSnapshot => {
    typesSnapshot.forEach(data => {
      //create a listener for this type
      firebase.database().ref(`entitiesNode/entities/${id}/children/${data.key}`).orderByValue().off()
    });
  });
  firebase.database().ref(`entitiesNode/entities/${id}`).off();
  //remove the entity from store
  store.dispatch({
    type: 'REMOVE_ENTITY',
    id: id
  });
}
```

Here is an example of our reducer for the entites.

```js
const defaultChildEntities = {
  0: [],
  1: [],
  2: [],
  3: [],
  4: [],
  5: [],
  6: []
}

export default function entities(state = {}, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'ADD/UPDATE_ENTITY_FROM_FB' :
    //need to make sure movingChildEntities does not come from store
    const entity = {childEntities: defaultChildEntities, ...state[action.id]};
    delete entity.childEntitiesMoving;
    delete entity.childEntitiesDocked;
    delete entity.newMoving;
    return {...state, [action.id]: {...entity, ...action.payload}}
    case 'UPDATE_ENTITY_LOCAL' :
    return {...state, [action.id]: {...state[action.id],...action.payload}}
    case 'REMOVE_ENTITY' :
    const newState = {...state}
    delete newState[action.id];
    return newState;
    case 'CLEAR_ENTITIES' :
    return {}
    default:
    return state;
  }
}
```

Here is an example of a connector we use for the canvas component:

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  const getAttributes = makeGetAttributes();
  let canvasID = ownProps.params.canvasID;
  //need to see if the object has entered store yet. If not then create a blank one for the app
  if (state.canvasPage.entities[canvasID] != undefined) {
    return {
      ...getAttributes(state, ownProps),
      canvasProps: state.canvasPage.canvasProps,
      dockedStacks: state.canvasPage.dockedEntities,
      editor: state.canvasPage.canvasEntityEditor,
      // stacks: entityObj.Stack,
      // uploads: entityObj.Upload,
      dragAndDrop: state.canvasPage.dragAndDrop,
      selections: state.canvasPage.selections,
      users: state.users
    }
  }

  return {
    canvasProps: state.canvasPage.canvasProps,
    dockedStacks: state.canvasPage.dockedEntities,
    editor: state.canvasPage.canvasEntityEditor,
    dragAndDrop: state.canvasPage.dragAndDrop,
    selections: state.canvasPage.selections,
    users: state.users
  }
}
```

We then use selectors to get the info from store

```js
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

const getAttributes = (state, props) => state.canvasPage.entities[props.params.canvasID];
const getCards = (state, props) => state.canvasPage.entities[props.params.canvasID].childEntities[2] || {};
const getStacks = (state, props) => state.canvasPage.entities[props.params.canvasID].childEntities[1] || {};
const getUploads = (state, props) => state.canvasPage.entities[props.params.canvasID].childEntities[6] || {};

export const makeGetAttributes = () => {
  return createSelector([getAttributes, getCards, getStacks, getUploads], (attributes, cards, stacks, uploads) => {
    return {
      ...attributes,
      cards,
      stacks,
      uploads
    }
  });
}
```

The issue we are having is getting the app to update at the correct times and not perform unnecessary updates. I feel we are at the point where we need a fresh set of eyes and some advice as to whether this is setup correctly.

Specifically when an entity is added to an entity, the change is showing up in react and redux dev tools but the ui is not being updated. Here is an example of the specific componenent in question.

```js
class CanvasStack extends React.Component {
  //no need to update the component if the canvas moved.
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps){
    //here we are comparing the all the props before and after the update. If the canvas position is the only thing that has changed then there is no need to waste resources on rerendering the components.
    let currentProps = {...this.props},
    futureProps = {...nextProps};
    delete currentProps.canvasProps;
    delete futureProps.canvasProps;
    delete currentProps.dragAndDrop;
    delete futureProps.dragAndDrop;
    return JSON.stringify(currentProps) !== JSON.stringify(futureProps);
  }

  render() {
    let stackID = this.props.stackID,
    styles = {},
    dataX = this.props.dataX,
    dataY = this.props.dataY,
    expanded = this.props.expanded || false,
    placeholder = this.props.placeholder || false,
    docked = this.props.docked || false,
    selected = this.props.selected || false,
    isMoving = this.props.isMoving || false;
    // stackLength = this.props.cards.length;


    //return the correct position
    styles[`transform`] = `translate(${dataX}px, ${dataY}px)`;
    //set the height and width
    styles[`height`] = this.props.height;
    styles[`width`] = this.props.width;

    if (expanded && selected) {
      styles[`border`] = `solid 2px  rgb(${this.props.users[selected].color})`
    }

    return (
      <div
        ref="stack"
        id={stackID}
        className={this.getClassNames(expanded, docked, isMoving, placeholder)}
        data-type="stack"
        style={styles}
        draggable="true"
        //needed to target itmes moving from the new items sidebar
        data-newMoving={this.props.newMoving}
        data-selected={selected ? true : false}
      >
        <StackInnerContent
          stackLength={10}
          {...this.props}
          ></StackInnerContent>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }

const makeMapStateToProps = () => {
  const getAttributes = makeGetAttributes(),
  getCards = makeGetCards(),
  getStacks = makeGetStacks(),
  getUploads = makeGetUploads();
  const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    let stackID = ownProps.stackID;
    if (state.canvasPage.entities[stackID] != undefined) {
      return {
        ...getAttributes(state, ownProps),
        cards: getCards(state, ownProps),
        stacks: getStacks(state, ownProps),
        uploads: getUploads(state, ownProps),
        authenticated: state.authenticated,
        canvasProps: state.canvasPage.canvasProps,
        dragAndDrop: state.canvasPage.dragAndDrop,
        users: state.users
      }
    } else {
      return {
        authenticated: state.authenticated,
        canvasProps: state.canvasPage.canvasProps,
        dragAndDrop: state.canvasPage.dragAndDrop,
        users: state.users
      }
    }
  }
  return mapStateToProps
}

export default connect(makeMapStateToProps)(CanvasStack)
```

The UI will update if i remove:

```js
    delete currentProps.dragAndDrop;
    delete futureProps.dragAndDrop;
```

from shouldComponentUpdate but this is not the correct behavior and it will lead to the component being update too many times. I know this is a very specific question and i apologize if there is not enough information. I tried to be as detailed as possible.

Comment: Format your code, it's looks like mess.

Comment: edited, sorry about that

Comment: Nice. It was really hard to read.